# toggling between start stop button jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey I'm trying to create a start stop button that toggle between each other in one button....I got it to work with stop but cant seem to get it to go back to START after that

heres a fiddle im working on

http://jsfiddle.net/hUYZv/4/

heres the js

```
 $('#start_timer_button').on('click', function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     $('.stop_button').removeClass('stop_button');
     $(this).text('stop').addClass('stop_button');
 });
```

heres the html

```
 <button id='start_timer_button'> Start Timer</button>
```

Comment: Why not just toggle the visibility of two completely different HTML elements? Could be within the same button as spans, or could be completely different button elements.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
$('#start_timer_button').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).text(function (_, text) {
        return text === 'stop' ? 'Start Timer' : 'stop';
    }).toggleClass('stop_button');
});
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/hUYZv/5/)

Comment: nice thank you i didnt even think about using the texts for a conditional thats brilliant.....

Answer (score 0):

Try setting up an if statement to check if it should start or stop.

```
if ($(this).hasClass('stop_button')) {
```

Here is the jsfiddle for it: [Start/Stop Button](http://jsfiddle.net/FzWnS/)